# Will the pcDuino work with cylon.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino, arduino-uno, cylon.js

I recently built a robot with an arduino that was controlled by a website with node. I used cylonjs to programm the robot with javascript. Unfortunately now I realized that I have to always have my computer connected to the addition for this to work.
 [cylon.js & arduino uno: execute program without cable connection to PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388539/cylon-js-arduino-uno-execute-program-without-cable-connection-to-pc)

The link states that I cannot connect the arduino to my pc so that I can run my cylonjs script.js without two xBee modules, which costs more than the arduino itself.

So I looked at the beaglebone and that would definitely work with colon but I didn't see anything about the pcDuino. Would that work exactly like an arduino?

I also could buy a raspberry pi  and run the nodejs  programm on that.

I'm not sure what to do. Other suggestions would be nice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arduino yun.. You can run nodejs on it.. and its compatible with all arduino shields and modules.. Has wifi to connect to your network and be remotely controlled.
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardYun

https://blog.arduino.cc/2014/05/06/time-to-expand-your-yun-disk-space-and-install-node-js/

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that's what the yun  did.